# images not displaying if user not logged in?

Tags: php, image, authentication, hyperlink

I am trying to show images with the link to a full size image to users who are logged in.
I am also trying to make it so that not logged in users can only see the thumbnail image without the full picture link and if they click the image they are taking to the login page.

So far i have created my code like this, it shows fine when the users logged in, but when the users logged out they cant see any images.

Can someone please show me where im going wrong. thank you.

```
<?php            
$photo = "data/photos/$profile[1]/pic1.jpg";
if (!file_exists($photo)) {
    $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
$thumb = "data/photos/$profile[1]/thumb_pic1.jpg";
if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
    $thumb = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
 if (logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"$photo\" rel=\"shadowbox\" title=\"$profile[2]'s Photo's\"><img src=\"$thumb\" width=\"90\" height=\"90\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
    }
if (!logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"loginframe.php\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\"><img src=\"thumb\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: src = $thumb vs. src=thumb  one is a variable, the other is a string

Comment: Did you consider checking the `<img>` tag in the generated HTML, when the image wasn't visible?

Answer (score 2):

Missing a `$` before `thumb` in logged-out case

```
<img src=\"thumb\"
          ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"loginframe.php\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\"><img src=\"thumb\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
}
```

Looking carefully, you're missing a $ in the img src.

```
if (!logged_in()) {
    echo
    "<li><a href=\"loginframe.php\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\"><img src=\"$thumb\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
    }
```

Also, you should use If-Else instead of checking twice